# Updating UI before reopening the activity

Tags: android

There is a verification link in activity. On clicking that link gmail app opens.User can verify through that mail. Now when users opens that activity again, the verification link should stay or go according to the response from api. The issue is after opening the activity,link disappears after fraction of second giving a flicker effect. I wan't that when activity is opened, if verification is true, link doesn't appear

Comment: Can you set visibility to gone in `onResume` and `onCreate` based on the indicator you get from the API?

Comment: Yes, doing that but that is giving a flicker effect. Link is visible for fraction of second before it hides.